# Install python2.7 unmet dependencies problems - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, packaging, python-2.7

I recently clean reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and now wanted to install python2.7 for various other dependencies, however am unable to do so. Running `sudo apt install python` and `sudo apt install python-minimal` both have very similar errors:

python:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python : PreDepends: python-minimal (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: python2.7 (>= 2.7.15~rc1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

python-minimal:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python-minimal : Depends: python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.15~rc1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: python but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing python2.7-minimal then outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python2.7-minimal : Depends: libpython2.7-minimal (= 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1) but 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 is to be installed
                     Recommends: python2.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing python2.7 runs into the exact same error as before, and libpython2.7 is already installed, since `apt-cache policy libpython2.7` returns:

```
libpython2.7:
  Installed: 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2
  Candidate: 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1 500
        500 http://ftp.ticklers.org/archive.ubuntu.org/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.ticklers.org/archive.ubuntu.org/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.7.15~rc1-1 500
        500 http://ftp.ticklers.org/archive.ubuntu.org/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Yes I have ran `sudo apt update` and `upgrade`, and I have been looking for answers for multiple days now without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I think the inability to install python2.7 might be related to Ubuntu not being able to recognize hardware ports (such as HDMI) and not being able to change the brightness.

Hardware information:
Product Name: Acer Aspire A715-72G
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz
Additional Graphics Card: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]

I am very new to Ubuntu, and Unix in general, so I hope it is a beginner mistake and it is easily fixable. This is the first question I have asked so if there is anything more I should add, please tell me so.

All help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

EDIT: Add the output of `sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://ftp.ticklers.org/archive.ubuntu.org/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                          
Hit:4 http://ftp.ticklers.org/archive.ubuntu.org/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                    
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu bionic InRelease                            
Hit:6 http://ftp.ticklers.org/archive.ubuntu.org/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                  
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Hit:8 http://ftp.ticklers.org/archive.ubuntu.org/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                   
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu bionic Release                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: I just added it, thanks for the quick reply! Iḿ pretty sure there are some problems, but I can't really decipher it.

Comment: The error is telling you to delete your deadsnakes PPA. It does not exist for 18.04. That won't solve your problem - try a different mirror, then `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt upgrade`, then try the install again.

Comment: Thank you, `sudo apt update` and `upgrade` work fine now, but the same error remains when attempting to install python and python2.7-minimal. Do you have any idea how to continue from there?

Comment: Would reccomend using pyenv to manage python versions, it will also install versions for you easily :)  https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would be knowing this and it is not a solution to your question but

Python 2.7 will not be maintained past 2020. Originally, there was no official date. Recently, that date has been updated to January 1, 2020.

Please avoid using [Python 2.7](https://pythonclock.org/)